# Drupal 6 cron cannot connect to mysql database

Tags: php, drupal, cron

I run quite few Drupal sites on my VPS CentOS server. Few of them are stuck on Drupal 6, however they run just fine.

One in particular I'm having problems with. Cron runs fine when I run it from the browser (mydomain.com/cron.php). But when run as a cron job, it fails producing the following error:

**The *mysql* error was: *Access denied for user 'my_username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)*.**

Actually, that happens when I run any other drupal page with php directly from the server (e.g. php ./index.php)

Does anyone have any idea why that would be happening? I never came across it, and I developed and maintained a lot of Drupal sites...

Comment: What user executes the script from `cli` and what from `website`?

Comment: The same user runs both. I even tried having the root user running the script from `cli`, but with the same result